# Recyclerview inside ViewPager changing ArrayList by next tab ArrayList

Tags: android

I am developing a news app. [this is my home page, I am using viewpager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0rmX.jpg)

On RecyclerView item click another tabbed activity is opening with the same ArrayList of RecyclerView. For this, there is one static ArrayList which I am using in inner activity for showing full news.

My problem is on item click of RecyclerView, it is not opening the same list of active tab because my static ArrayList is updating with the list of next tab.

How can I resist this ArrayList for not updating the next tab list.

Comment: post ur code plzzz

Comment: show ur static array list and the host activity so that we try to analyze where the flaw's happening

Answer (score 1):

Thank You For accepting my question but later I solved this problem.
I am not using static ArrayList anymore instead I am generating previous list again in my inner Activity, so it is updating only once and not giving problem anymore.
Thank You

Comment: You seem like a passionate android developer